# python caught exception stacktrace vs uncaught exception stacktrace

Tags: python-2.7

I have a try except block in my code where I am expecting a django.core.exceptions.ValidationError kind of excepption, catching it and logging it. I have tried various ways to log the exception, from simple logger.excepption to all the functions from traceback library. following is the stacktrace I get everytime:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/belong/work/code/hulk/hulk/commons/decorators.py", line 48, in func_wrapper
    func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/belong/work/code/hulk/hulk/job/views.py", line 211, in create
    raise DjangoCoreValidationError('test')
ValidationError: [u'test']
```

Whereas, if I dont catch the exception at all, python logs it as an uncaught exception and I get the following stacktrace:

```
2019-07-09 06:09:56,445 ERROR MainProcess [hulk.commons.exceptions.handlers: 35] [oid: 706a0f00ea9d476291ba118e61576622] [strail: hulk] [aid: ] Uncaught exception
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/belong/work/code/hulk/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 480, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/belong/work/code/hulk/hulk/job/views.py", line 211, in create
    raise DjangoCoreValidationError('test')
ValidationError: [u'test']
```

Why are these 2 different? Is there any way I can get the same stacktrace as the uncaught one while catching and logging the same exception?